# Issue in sending error message from backend(nodejs) to frontend(reactjs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am implementing a login feature, so when the user enter wrong credentials, I am passing an error  'Wrong Credentials' to the frontend, but at frontend I receive a different error message.

**this is the relevant backend code**

```
exports.loginUser = async (req, res) => {
  try{
    const loggedinUser = await userService.loginUser(res, req.body);
    if(loggedinUser.error){
      throw new Error(loggedinUser.error); //loggedinUser.error is 'Wrong credentials'
    }
    const tokenPayload = {
      userName: loggedinUser[0].name,
      email: loggedinUser[0].email
    }
    const token = jwt.sign(tokenPayload, keys.JWT.TOKEN_SECRET, {expiresIn: '60m'} );
    const tokenData = {
      token: token,
      name: tokenPayload.userName,
      email: tokenPayload.email
    }
    const redirectURL = url.format({
      pathname: '/dashboard/buzz',
      query: tokenData
    });
    res.send({redirectTo: redirectURL});
  } catch(err){
    console.log(err); //prints wrong credentials
    res.status(400).json(err);
  }
}
```

**this is the relevant frontend code**

```
const loginHandler = ( event ) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        setShowValidationMessage(true);

        const loginDetails = {
            email: loginForm.email.value,
            password: loginForm.password.value
        }

        if(formIsValid){
            axios.post('http://localhost:5000/login', loginDetails)
                .then(res=>setRedirectURL(res.data.redirectTo))
                .catch(err=>{
                    console.log(err.message);// prints Request failed with status code 400
                });
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think the `message` returned by server is stored in `err.response`.

Comment: the message should appear in err.response.data, but that's empty

Comment: Btw, I found a way, in place of ` res.status(400).json(err) ` , write ` res.status(400).json({message: err.message}) ` and at the front in err.response.data, the message will be present.